# I need MySQL query that loops through a double array stored in table column and sums the results

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a column in the database that stores an array of paid invoices. Each payment consists of another array containing the payment amount, the date and the payer's name.
The delimiter of the first array is "&" and the second delimiter is "/"

Complete array looks like this:

```
10.00/2023-05-03/petar&100.00/2023-05-09/petar&6344.00/2023-05-09/petar
```

I need a query that will go through a double array and sum up all payments (regardless of date and name), specifically for this example 10.00+100.00+6344.00 = 6454.00

I tried with `SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(payments,'/',1),'&',1)`
but in that case I getting just first part of array and I need a sum of all parts

Comment: Better start fixing table design

Comment: Store amount, date & name in a separate table along with the invoice id as a foreign key. And remove this column from the main invoice table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the query wrote by @selvazi shall suffice your problem. However, this is not the most efficient and optimistic way to deal with arithmetic on how you store your data and how you will process the computation. Using cross joins should create temporary tables which affects your query and your database plus using complex calls to subsequent string functions can affect the performance of your index fields, if they are indexed. But based on how you store your data, it is a bad design, unfortunately.

Your best way to deal with this is to handle the data outside MySQL. For example, pull the data or retrieve the data from MySQL and then manage the string manipulation to filter or transform it to array using your backend scripts. This way shall be faster and quicker. You can also designate the backend process from another server isolated from the database server so it has more power to process the data especially when your data is big.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSON_TABLE` to convert comma separated column into rows :

Before convert your column into rows, we need to convert it into a valid json by replacing & into ',' using `CONCAT('["' , replace(t.payments, '&', '", "') , '"]')`

Then extract price from each extracted element using your SUBSTRING query :

```
SELECT t.id, SUM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(tt.payement,'/',1),'&',1)) as payement
FROM mytable t
cross join  JSON_TABLE(
          CONCAT('["' , replace(t.payments, '&', '", "') , '"]'),
          "$[*]"
          COLUMNS(
              payement varchar(50) PATH "$"
              )
      ) AS tt
group by t.id
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/U9i924yy)